# How can I get a friend to stop thinking global and start thinking relative?

Tags: java, oop, variables, pointers, object

I have a friend who is struggling to learn OO programming (in a Computer Science class), mainly, I believe, due to the fact that he does not understand the relativity/difference between "type" and the actual "instance." It appears to be an issue in understanding how data is stored.

He knows variables, and control structures, and quite a few algorithms, but I think understanding scope and the way objects are defined in Java is confusing to him. The most confusing part is the "template" part, where the methods and variables are defined, but are "owned" by each object.

As this post kind of shows, I'm horrible at explaining this concept, even when I know I'm explaining it to people.

So what I want to know, is how can **clearly explain to him instances and classes (as a type, versus the actual data).** He knows the basic concept, I think,  but does not fully understand the difference between type and data, and how the data is passed around.

---

More info:

Here's the sort of confusion he is experiencing. We're working with overriding a Critter object in GridWorld (The horribly designed AP test object thing). In any event, we are suppose to redefine some methods.

He'll end up trying to use methods as properties (quite possibly a typo, but also because stuff like GetLocation() may be confusing), or he'll try to use methods on the wrong variable, or not use the right type of variable.

The difference between "Integer nameHere" and "nameHere Integer" is confusing, I think, to him. He may try to do Integer.equals() when he should do nameHere.equals(). I show him the API, but I think it's just plaining confusing.

How do you explain the difference between type and variable, but not only that, but show how a variable can have other variables in it, how when you write

```
public getSomething()
{
    return something;
}
```

You are getting specific data from the class you instantiated, oh, and by the way, it's different for every single object?

How can I get him to stop thinking "global" and start thinking "relative"? How do you explain "relative"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use TVs to explain OOP concepts. There are "TVs" as a class, but then there's your TV, in your house. It can do some things that  ALL TVs can do, like show a picture, turn on and off, etc.

But it also has a locally defined scope because it is one instance of the class of TVs in the world. If you enter channel 32 on a TV in NYC you get one thing. If you do it in Bangalore, you get something else. Entering a channel is like calling the TV's `setChannel(int channel)` method.

It's not surprising to users of such real world objects that they work this way. My advice for this particular problem is to stop using abstract and technical language to describe the basic concepts. There are plenty of things in computer science that can't be explained using material objects in the real world, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

One can think of classes as a mould, like a mould define how a final product would look like, classes define what all data can be stored, how it can be retrieved, accessed etc.

One can put raw material in mould and get the product and start using it.
Similarly one can create an instance of Class and start using it.

Each object can hold different data (like in mould you can put green liquid, red liquid etc) but there is only a single way to access data defined my class semantics (like final shape of mould product would be identical).

Hope it helps